# Search for a real word in random character sequence without spaces - java

Tags: java, regex, full-text-search, character

Although i am not new in java i came across a problem that i am having difficulties solving. What i want to do is 
- Take two arguments as inputs 
1. Random char sequence consisting of TCGA i.e. // TGTTTGCCAGTGCGTAGCATGCTACT
2. List of words that consists of A,C,G,T i.e. // AT, TACT, TAG etc

And when these two arguments are passed, program searches for matches. However if there are two or more of the same word; i.e program has found 2x TAG in the sequence only one is counted. All applicable words are counted in given sequence and returned in form of a print stm for example.

Comment: What exactly is your question? This seems to be a fairly straightforward task.

Comment: [`String.indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @Pointy I am doing pen and paper approach currently, will tackle this in IDE in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split argument 2 into a list of words, then use indexOf() to find the matches:

```
for(String word: words){
   if (arg1.indexOf(word) > 0) System.out.println(word);
}
```

The rest you can do your self :)